# Radio Buttons in netbeans

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I have a simple question?

how do i save an option from a radio button into a table of a database after hit the save button?

i'm using netbeans ide and an sqlite3 database with sqlite studio.

Comment: get the option and save it.too broad

Comment: i was expecting for an example but thanks for your answer.

Comment: put your code, your question is not clear, what you use to insert to database JPA, or native query or what, like that you can't help us to help you, so put your code

Comment: i'm using a PreparedStatement "insert into change_cvp () values ()" to save all the data from the textbox but can't do the same for the radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the value of your RadioButton,
for Radio button there only two choices **TRUE mean selected, FALSE mean not selected**, so you will get true or false like that:

```
RadioButton rd = new RadioButton();
boolean value = rd.isSelected();
```

Second just persiste this value in database.

```
String requete = "INSERT INTO mytable(valueOfMyradioButton) values(?)";

statement = connection.prepareStatement(requete);

statement.setString(1, value);
```

Good luck.